# Might transactional backup cause the operations to be deadlock, etc?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, database-backups

In SQL Server, I get Full and Transactional Log Backup (full: once in a day, transactional: hourly during workimng hours). As far as I see, there are some advantages of transactinal log backup over differential backup. Rearding to these issues, could you clarify me about the following points?

**1.** When getting transactional backup hourly during employees continue their operations with the data, might there be some problems like deadlock, or corruption of the data? I use job script in SQL Server Management Studio to get backup, but have no idea how SQL Server treats the records that are currently started to be edited.

**2.** In general looking, what do you suggest for backup selection in addition to full backup? Transactional Log or Differential backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No :)

Backups using the backup command do not require locks on any user tables.
Transaction log backups are usually more frequent than hourly, would your company really be okay with loosing an hours worth of data if something bad happened to you database disks?

Your schedule needs to depend on what your requirements are for your RPO (recovery point objective) and RTO (recovery time objective). If can only sustain 5 minutes worth of lost data then a 5 minute transaction log backup is required. If you can only cope with 1 hour worth of downtime then you need to make sure that you have data backups that can be restored and recovered in that amount of time  - the first part will depend on how optimized your restore is (ie how long it takes to read the backups from your backup drives and write the data files back to your data drives - [https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4935/optimize-sql-server-database-restore-performance/#:~:text=%20Optimize%20SQL%20Server%20Database%20Restore%20Performance%20,restore%20the%20database%20by%20using%20some...%20More%20](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4935/optimize-sql-server-database-restore-performance/#:%7E:text=%20Optimize%20SQL%20Server%20Database%20Restore%20Performance%20,restore%20the%20database%20by%20using%20some...%20More%20) has some ideas. The second part will depend on how much transaction log data needs to be read and applied back to the database to recover it to the desired point.

You might find that you simply can't do full database backups fast enough, in those cases incremental backups could work as there's less data to write but SQL Server will then have to put it back together.

Of course, if the restore is happening manually then you also need to account for human time in there!

It's a good idea to try out your backup and recovery process (before PROD!), this way you can tell if you're going to need to optimize the process further.

Comment: Thanks for reply, voted up. **1.** In this case, for getting backup frequently (let's say hourly) is TRA a good option than DIF backup? Or can we use each of them separately in addition to FULL (I mean FULL + TRA (hourly) or FULL + DIFF (hourly))?  **2.** What is the general approach for MSSQL Backup? I was simply get FULL once a day and TRA hourly as I mentioned. But is there also a need to get DIFF? If so, what should be its frequency according to this example?

Comment: You should be taking transaction log backups regardless - otherwise your transaction log will have to keep growing to allow you to do recovery to certain points in time. How often you do them will depend on your requirements, but typically you would probably start with Full backups each night and transaction log backups every 5 minutes. But you need to be absolutely certain whatever you do it's to match your requirements - people get very annoyed if you loose data.

Comment: **1.** What about DIFF backup in this scenario? If I get FULL daily and TRA for 5 min each, how frequent should I get DIFF? And if I get DIFF hourly, then what it let me for restore? Assume that I lost data at 08:16 AM. Then will I able to use FULL (get at 03:00 AM) and then get the latest DIFF (get an 08:00 AM) and then 3 TRA backup (get at 08:05, 08:10 and 08:15 AM)? Is this scenario true in such cases?

Comment: **2.** And If theer is no DIFF then I would use TRA backups from teh beginng of 03:AM. Is that true?

Comment: You don't need DIFF unless you can't support just using full backups. Yes, you would use the last full backup before the incident + the last differential backup (each of your hourly ones will get bigger and bigger) before the incident + the transaction logs data from the next transaction log backups to the point in time you need to recover to. Yes, without differentials then you would just apply the transaction log backups that cover more time. Taking the differential backups will be more intensive than taking transaction backups but restoration times will likely be similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanations. In this scene I also see that tere is no need to worry about the locks, etc. on the transaction that are started after the backup proces is started.Is that true?

Comment: Yeah, that's true.